Ubuntu is unable to identify display
Ubuntu Jammy and now Noble are unable to identify the display on my ASUS Vivobook 17 which has an AMD Ryzen 3 gpu.
It is stuck at 800x600.
I have I dual boot with Windows 11 which doesn’t have that problem.
How do I fix this?
root@VivoBook:/home/paul# xrandr
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 800 x 600, maximum 4096 x 4096
None-1 connected primary 800x600+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 0mm x 0mm
800x600       60.00*+
root@VivoBook:/home/paul# ubuntu-drivers list
root@VivoBook:/home/paul# ubuntu-drivers devices
root@VivoBook:/home/paul#
My laptop is a Vivobook 17 Model M172D

I have never used AMD on Ubuntu before as Intel/Nvidia seem to be better supported but have you installed any Linux drivers/software from AMD? I think they do provide some Linux drivers. Also I would suggest you update your original question with more info. Exactly what model of Vivobook? Exactly which model of Ryzen 3. Also update your original question with the full results of running xrandr in a terminal in case it's relevant.

Please Edit your Q (above) and paste the output of $ ubuntu-drivers list and                      $ ubuntu-drivers devices

The available settings for the display are controlled by the graphics card and the driver been used for that card. The exact model of video card and the kernel being used by the OS are important to solve this kind of issue. Please edit the question and add this info.
